# Bootstrap 3 toggle button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
             <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
                </div>
                 <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

After editing the toggle button, my button is no longer working, can anyone help point out the error please.

Comment: Please provide the exact page where you are using it if possible ,or a test page reproducing the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, so the issue must lie somewhere else. Here's a fiddle of your exact code and a fresh copy of jQuery and Bootstrap 3:

https://jsfiddle.net/aL589uc4/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```